# Trying to fetch data from firestore coming up as nil with Swiftui

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I've setup my Firebase Authentication within my app to register users and save their sign-up information which works perfectly. However when I try to fetch the data to populate their profile screen (with their names, profile pic, etc.), the app crashes saying it unwrapped an optional value with came up as nil. I did a print function that shows whether or not the information is actually being pulled from firestore and it is. I'm not sure why everytime I try to load my profile screen it crashes. Is there something i'm doing wrong or is there a problem with Auth?

User Model Code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct User: Encodable, Decodable{

var uuid: String
var email: String
var profileImageUrl: String
var firstname: String
var lastname: String 
}
```

Auth Service

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestore


class AuthService {

static var storeRoot = Firestore.firestore()

static func getUserId(userid: String) -> DocumentReference {
    return storeRoot.collection("users").document(userid)
}

static func signUp(firstname: String, lastname:String, email: String, password: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping (_ user: User) -> Void, onError: @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void) {
    
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) {
        (authData, error) in
        
        if error != nil {
            onError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let userId = authData?.user.uid else {return}
        
        let storageProfileUserId = StorageService.storageProfileId(userId: userId)
        
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
        
        StorageService.saveProfileImage(userId: userId, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, email: email, imageData: imageData, metaData: metadata, storageProfileImageRef: storageProfileUserId, onSuccess: onSuccess, onError: onError)
    }
}


static func signIn(email: String, password: String, onSuccess: @escaping (_ user: User) -> Void, onError:
                    @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void) {
    
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password){
        (authData, error) in
        
        if error != nil {
            onError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        guard let userId = authData?.user.uid else {return}
        
        let firestoreUserId = getUserId(userid: userId)
        
        firestoreUserId.getDocument{
            
            (document, error) in
           if let dict = document?.data() {
                guard let decodedUser = try? User.init(fromDictionary: dict) else {return}
            
            onSuccess(decodedUser)
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

SessionStore:

```swift
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionStore, Never>()
    @Published var session: User? {
        didSet { self.didChange.send(self) }
    }
    
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    func listen() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                let firestoreUserId = AuthService.getUserId(userid: user.uid)
                firestoreUserId.getDocument { (document, error) in
                    if let dict = document?.data() {
                        guard let decodedUser = try? User.init(fromDictionary: dict) else { return }
                        let dataDescription = document?.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
                        self.session = decodedUser
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("User not found")
                self.session = nil
            }
        })
        
    }
    
    func logout() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        } catch {
            
        }
    }
    
    func unbind() {
        if let handle = handle {
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        unbind()
    }
}
```

This is line of code that returns the error on my profile screen when I try to unwrap the value:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI


struct AccountViewNew: View {
    
    
    
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    
    func getUser() {
        
        session.listen()
    }
    
    var user: User?
    var body: some View {
       
      
                    VStack (alignment: .leading){
                        HStack {
                            Text(user?.firstname ?? "Change")
                                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            
                            Text(user?.lastname ?? "Your Name")
                                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        } 
                        .onAppear(perform: getUser)
```

Comment: You should avoid force unwrapping if at all possible (it's OK for things like URLs created from a static string, but in this case, I'd avoid it at all costs). You should also use Codable to map data from Firestore to Swift: https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/. Also, in most cases you probably also don't need a `User` struct, as Firebase does have a `User` object already - so if you don't store extra information about a user, use the built-in `User` class.

Comment: To answer the question why thew `user` property is `nil`, we need to see how you you connect the view to the view model, can you please update your code snippet? Thanks!

Comment: @PeterFriese I updated the View code to show the bindings. I also changed the force unwrap to optional for the names.

Comment: In your code, AccountViewNew,user will always be `nil`, even if you call `getUser()` - there is no code that updates the the `user` property. You probably want to access the user in the `SessionStore` instead.

Comment: Ah yes, that seems to have done it. Much respect @PeterFriese